# Update one row based on value in another row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have an table with following columns and values:

```
SubscriptionName, Status, Ignore
Project Plan 3 for faculty, Enabled, Null
Project Plan 3 for faculty, Suspended, Null
```

How can I update the `Ignore` column to `True` for the suspended record, if there are 2 entries with the same `subscriptionName` and the other record has the value `Enabled` in `Status`

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? The syntax of `update` statements is quite database-specific.

Comment: Does it need to be just 2 entries? Or all the entries that is greater than 1?

Comment: Does it always have to be the suspended entry?
Can't you: update table xxxx
set Ignore = 'True'
where SubscriptionName = 'Project Plan 3 for faculty' and Status = 'Suspended'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do this with window functions and an updatable CTE:

```
with cte (
    select 
        t.*,
        max(case when status = 'Enabled' then 1 end) 
            over(partition by SubscriptionName) has_enabled
    from mytable t
)
update cte 
set ignore = 'True'
where status = 'Suspended' and has_enabled = 1
```

The conditional window `max()` checks if another row exists with the same `SubscriptionName` and status `'Enabled'`.

Or you can use `exists`:

```
update t 
set ignore = 'True'
from mytable t
where 
    status = 'Suspended' 
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from mytable t1 
        where t1.SubscriptionName = t.SubscriptionName and t1.status = 'Enabled'
    )
```